# How to split a string by white space or comma?

Tags: javascript

If I try

```
"my, tags are, in here".split(" ,")
```

I get the following

```
[ 'my, tags are, in here' ]
```

Whereas I want

```
['my', 'tags', 'are', 'in', 'here']
```

Comment: don't you mean whitespace *or* comma?

Comment: As an explanation for the result that you're getting: `"my, tags are, in here".split(" ,")` will split the string only where a space _followed_ by a comma is the separator. Your string does not contain that sequence, hence it is not splitted. 
`"my, tags are, in here".split(", ")` with the splitting sequence swapped will at least split your original string in three parts, after each comma-and-space.
If you do want five parts, the answers below specify the match string as a regular expression matching a space _or_ a comma.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

[`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can also accept a regular expression:

```
input.split(/[ ,]+/);
```

This particular regex splits on a sequence of one or more commas or spaces, so that e.g. multiple consecutive spaces or a comma+space sequence do not produce empty elements in the results.

Comment: @Bergi: Well, it's both more strict than what I suggest (only one comma allowed, in front) and more loose (split on all whitespace) than what the OP asked for. IMHO it would be simply worse -- consider the input `spaces , before commas`.

Comment: @Jon: OK, that depends on the OPs needs. I wouldn't plenk :-)

Comment: +1 I know this is a little old but why use a blank space and not `\s`. I may have some line breaks in the blob and `\s` takes care of those too.

Comment: FACEPALM NOTE: don't put quotes around the regex.  e.g. Don't use `input.split("/[ ,]+/)"`. Leave the quotes out (`input.split(//)` instead of `input.split("//")`) and you'll have a much better experience. Because oddly, that would really probably only work on *itself* (to generate `["input.split(\"", ")\""]`).

Comment: input.split(/[ ,]+/);

Comment: it also removes empty strings from begin and end of the input : `' ,my, tags, are, here,'.replace(/[\s,]+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ')`

Answer (score 69):

you can use regex in order to catch any length of white space, and this would be like:

```
var text = "hoi how     are          you";
var arr = text.split(/\s+/);

console.log(arr) // will result : ["hoi", "how", "are", "you"]

console.log(arr[2]) // will result : "are"
```

Comment: Beware leading/trailing whitespace when using `/\s+/`. For example, `'a b c '.split(/\s+/) === [ 'a', 'b', 'c', '' ]`. If you `.trim()` the string first, you'll be good.

Answer (score 49):

The suggestion to use `.split(/[ ,]+/)` is good, but with natural sentences sooner or later you'll end up getting empty elements in the array. e.g. `['foo', '', 'bar']`.

Which is fine if that's okay for your use case. But if you want to get rid of the empty elements you can do:

```
var str = 'whatever your text is...';
str.split(/[ ,]+/).filter(Boolean);
```

Comment: Thats a very clever use of native object implicit constructors- my computers keyboard is mad this morning- I'll edit this comment later- but point is invoking Boolean like 'Boolean()' will construct a new instance of [object Boolean] with a value of false, just as would invoking 'new Boolean()'. That will filter out all matches down to this default behaviour. Nice one :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "natural sentences"? I couldn't emulate it nor do I understand what this is supposed to do.

Comment: It's explained by @VLostBoy. When the `Boolean()` constructor is called on any value, it casts that value to a boolean - true or false. Thus, any falsy values will be filtered from the array, including empty strings.

Comment: btw, you can use implicit constructors for other similar fun stuff, like `[1, 2, 3].map(String)`

Comment: Handle other types of whitespace (including newlines): `val.split(/[\s,]+/).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: `"foo, bar,,foobar,".split(/[\s,]+/)` returns `["foo", "bar", "foobar", ""]` (because of the dangling comma at the end), thanks!

Answer (score 13):

```
"my, tags are, in here".split(/[ ,]+/)
```

the result is :

```
["my", "tags", "are", "in", "here"]
```

Answer (score 13):

`input.split(/\s*[\s,]\s*/)`

… `\s*` matches zero or more white space characters (not just spaces, but also tabs and newlines).

... `[\s,]` matches one white space character or one comma

Comment: Nop. That's not good. This is the output : ["my", "tags are", "in here"]

Comment: it seems to split on each character.

Comment: @Marco Oops. Probably should have tested it before I made that last edit. I have now, and this time it really should work.

Comment: Hmm, how is this better than the accepted answer? `"foo,bar,foobar".split(/[ ,]+/)` returns `["foo", "bar", "foobar"]` as well.

Comment: @RafałCieślak As you can see from the timestamps, I provided my answer more or less at the same time as the accepted answer. Ie: When I wrote this answer, the question didn't have any answers.

Comment: @KaptajnKold Oh, I didn't catch that, thanks for answering!

Comment: `test test` is resulting in `["t", "", "e", "", "s", "", "t", " ", "t", "", "e", "", "s", "", "t"]`

Comment: @leonheess I'm embarrassed to say that you're right. I've removed the part of the answer that was wrong. Sheesh! This answer has not been my finest work. I really should learn to test things.

Answer (score 3):

When I want to take into account extra characters like your commas (in my case each token may be entered with quotes), I'd do a string.replace() to change the other delimiters to blanks and then split on whitespace.

Comment: `str_variable.replace(/[,'"]+/gi, ' ').split(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

When you need to split a string with some *single* char delimiters, consider using a reverse logic: match chunks of strings that consist of chars other than the delimiter chars.

So, to extract all chunks of chars other than whitespace (matched with `\s`) and commas, you can use

```js
console.log("my, tags are, in here".match(/[^\s,]+/g))
// => ["my","tags","are","in","here"]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMOwMt/1). `String#match` extracts all non-overlapping occurrences of one or more (`+`) chars other than whitespace and comma (`[^\s,]`).