# How can I parse an attribute directive which has multiple values?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'd like to implement a directive that lets me define a list of animals on an element. If the user likes all of those animals, I want to show the element; otherwise, I want to hide it. Ideally, I'd like it to look like this:

```
<div animals="cat dog horse"></div>
```

As you can see, the animals are space-separated, similar to how you can define an element's class with multiple values.

My proposed logic for the directive:

```
app.directive('animals ', function(userService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // how to parse the attribute and get an array of animal strings?
            var animalsArray = ... ?

            if (userService.likesAllAnimals(animalsArray))
            {
              // show element
            }
            else
            {
              // hide element
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But I'm lost as to how to:

1. Parse the `animals` attribute and derive `animalsArray` from it.
2. Show and hide the element.

Help?

Comment: You could use String.split(" ") to parse your `animals` attribute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346722/how-can-i-split-a-javascript-string-by-white-space-or-comma  Have you searched for how to hide & show/ automatically make visible in AngularJS?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I thought about using `split`, I just was wondering if there was a built-in Angular way of parsing an attribute that has space-separated values.

Comment: Can the elements that you add in directive, not be added in controller. Why use directive? Then it is just a matter of show and hide.

Comment: Because it looks really nice done declaratively. I'm going to be using this directive a lot on the same page, so it will be easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
app.directive('animals', function(userService) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var animals = attrs.animals.split(' ');

      if (userService.likesAllAnimals(animals))
        element.css('display', 'block');
      else
        element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  };
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1vadminKwS1TqllB8r9a?p=preview).

You can do this as well:

```
app.directive('animals', function(userService, $parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var animals = $parse(attrs.animals)(scope);

      if (userService.likesAllAnimals(animals))
        element.css('display', 'block');
      else
        element.css('display', 'none');
    }
  };
});
```

And now you can pass an actual array to the directive:

```
<div animals="['cat','dog','horse']">
```

or

```
<div ng-init="list=['cat','dog','horse']" animals="list">
```

Another Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTO1Qj2gUQ64TxuyElge?p=preview).