# Is there a way for Algolia to create separate refinement facets from a comma delineated JSON field

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I'm new to Algolia search.  My setup is React and Firebase, where my Firebase users table is being indexed in Algolia.  I'm using a refinementList widget and tags to allow users to filter better, but I'm wondering if there's a way to separate words in a field as separate refinements.  For example:

```
colors: "red, blue, green, white"
```

Is there a way to structure my data to have those colors as separate items in the refinementList or tag cloud?  I tried using brackets, a technique I saw in another stack overflow post, but that didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algolia works with arrays, so the solution is to change `colors: "red, blue, green, white"` to `colors: ["red, "blue", "green", "white"]`, you can do that with

```
var colors =  "red, blue, green, white,value with space"

var splitColors = colors.split(/[,]+/).map(str=>str.trim())
```

Then you can push `splitColors` as the `colors` attribute on Algolia

see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/23728809/3185307

Comment: Thanks Haroen.  I put an array in firebase and it worked correctly.

Comment: @HaroenViaene I am also stuck with the same issue of structuring comma separated data as refinement list in algolia, but the issue is that I am using shopify to save comma separated values to metafields using CustomField chrome extension, here the values are stored as strings to algolia so it is indexed as such to filter the products. It would be helpful, if we could get a solutuion in shopify to solve the above issue.

Comment: @sarojal, I think you sent a support email about that. You'll get an answer

Comment: @HaroenViaene Already sent the mail to the support team, and we are waiting for the reply...